# Sensitivity analysis (sobol) matches multiple formal arguments

Tags: r

I am trying to perform a sensitivity analysis for the first time in R Studio. Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sensitivity)

# Define the function to calculate Pill0 based on the model
calculate_Pill0 <- function(D0, r0) {
  return (1 - exp(-D0 * r0))
}

# Define the model inputs and their probability distributions
n_samples <- 10000  # Number of Monte Carlo samples
set.seed(123)  # Set a seed for reproducibility

# Define the probability distributions for each variable
c0 <- rbeta(n_samples, 0.2464, 0.1137)
h <- runif(n_samples, 1.97e-2, 2.34e-2)
A <- runif(n_samples, 100, 2000)
FHM <- rgamma(n_samples, shape = 2, scale = 0.5)
FD <- rgamma(n_samples, shape = 2.1, scale = 0.17)
VD <- runif(n_samples, 0.5, 524)
t1 <- rbeta(n_samples, 0.5259, 0.9763) * 60

# Calculate D0 and Vingestion based on the model
D0 <- VD * FD * t1 / (1e3)
Vingestion <- (h * A * FHM + VD * FD) * t1 / (1e3)

# Sensitivity analysis for each variable
sensitivity_results <- sobol(
  model = calculate_Pill0,
  X = list(
    D0 = D0,
    r0 = rlnorm(n_samples, meanlog = log(0.0000005), sdlog = 1)
  ),
  order = 2,  # Sensitivity order (can be adjusted)
  nboot = 100  # Number of bootstrap replications
)
```

Tried modifying this code. However, it keeps showing these errors:

```
1. Error in sobol(model = calculate_Pill0, X = list(D0 = D0, r0 = rlnorm(n_samples,  : 
  argument 2 matches multiple formal arguments. Or,

2. Error in sensitivity(fun = calculate_Pill0, p = list(c0 = c0, h = h, A = A,  : 
  could not find function "sensitivity".
```

I do not know how to fix it, please, some help will be appreciated!

Comment: After looking at the `?sobol` in a recently installed version of the `sensitivity` package, I'm trying to figure out why you are not making your arguments match the types of arguments in the help page. There's no `X` list argument, rather there are an `X` and an `X2` argument, and they are both dataframes. I'm wondering if you are trying to used\ code that you scraped from some blog that was using a different package?